# Difference between RL n and RLA CPU instructions

Tags: emulation, gameboy

According to the GameBoy manual, these instructions are as follows:

`rla            17           4 000c rotate akku left through carry`

`rl   r         CB 1x        8 z00c rotate left through carry`

However, I'm having hard time understanding the difference between them from the implementation point of view. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RL` sets Z flag depending on the result.

`RLA` clears Z regardless of the result.

Other than that they're identical in their implementation.